# Error with openmp for Nested for-loop

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have used Eigen library in my object oriented cpp code. I defined a main object, 2DGF, and in some methods of it, I have used openmp. Now I want to use openmp in another method as following:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(NON) 
   #pragma omp for 
for(unsigned int iE=0;iE<NE;iE++){
   for(unsigned int iK=0;iK<NK;iK++){
      for(unsigned int ii=0; ii<NL ;ii++){
          for(unsigned int jj=0; jj<NL ;jj++){
              if(abs(CoorX[ii]-CoorX[jj])<DiogLim){
                 G.insert(iE*NL+ii,iK*NL+jj)=0;
                 GR.insert(iE*NL+ii,iK*NL+jj)=0;
                 S.insert(iE*NL+ii,iK*NL+jj)=0;   
                 SR.insert(iE*NL+ii,iK*NL+jj)=0;   
              }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

where G, GR, S and SR are sparse matrices. Without using openmp it works with no problem. But when I use the openmp, I receive the following error: 
2DGF : malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
May anybody help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Eigen. But I read a bit in their [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#af2e35643f264387de3d72e3413d6e654)
About the method insert() of SparseMatrix it says that it is `reserving room` for other inserts.
Did you reserve enough space for all inserts?

If not, then it could be the same bug that is present in the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    std::vector< int > vInts;

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        vInts.push_back( i );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This might also end in an segmentation fault. Reason is that the vector is relocated to a different region int memory. This can be avoided by reserving enough memory for the vector. In this case `vInts.reserve(1000)`.

SparseMatrix also offers a reserve method. Try this, at least to rule it out as a possible bug.

**Edit:**
Here is the code with your for-loops and a simple assignment in the innermost loop. The program compiles with `g++ -fopenmp -Wall -Werror main.cpp` without error or warnings. The program executes normally with the ouput that i=99.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>

#define NON 3

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    unsigned int NE = 100;
    unsigned int NK = 100;
    unsigned int NL = 100;

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(NON) 
        #pragma omp for 
    for(unsigned int iE=0;iE<NE;iE++){
       for(unsigned int iK=0;iK<NK;iK++){
          for(unsigned int ii=0; ii<NL ;ii++){
              for(unsigned int jj=0; jj<NL ;jj++){
                  i = jj;
              }
           }
        }
    } 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the error is not related to SparseMatrix because, I made them comment but the error is present yet.

Comment: What about `CoorX`? What is it and have you tried commenting out the whole if-clause?

Comment: Yes, I'm now sure that is just related to openmp. If you want to try it, just use a four-level nested for-loop with openmp parallelizing of outer loop.

Comment: See my edit. It might also be, that your problem is not OpenMP itself, but a combination between OpenMP and your Compiler, Operating System, ... . Have you tried your code on different machines, with another compiler? Does my code compile and execute fine?

Comment: I compiled and tested your code. It works well on my computer. I use g++ compiler. But when I copied it into my code, it gives the 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' error. It is strange, makes me crazy....

Comment: I don't know any solution. Try to expand a small working version until the problem arises again (or remove as much as possible from a version that doesn't work). Maybe then it will be clearer or someone can help you. Good luck.